# .Net 5.0 400 404 Response Body Format

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

I am using .net 5.0 web api, i am getting standing response body for 404 400 which i want to much simple json

In built response

```
{
  "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
  "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
  "status": 400,
  "traceId": "00-bfac5ebcfa912b4db4ea94285448d797-13778d903ee0e547-00",
  "errors": {
    "Person.Invoice": [
      "invalid locationId, not in agreed range."
    ]
  }
}
```

I want it to much simple as standard  like

> ```
> {
>   "status": "FAIL",
>   "ref": "ABVD1232323232",
>   "errorDetails": "invalid locationId, not in agreed range."
> }
> ```

I can do in controller but i have duplicate this code in every web api request, instead i am trying to aim globally using middleware or attributes and cannot figure it how to do it.

Comment: Status should always be a number.  Not a string "Fail".  The error Details is the string with the message.

Comment: just an example, is something client wants specific nothing to do with status code as those already in httpstatucode returnd